# Plotting both date and hour with a counter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I have the following data :

```
    Unnamed: 0  PanelistID
Date                                       
2020-05-31 17:25:13           0     5555161
2020-05-31 17:26:13           1     5555161
2020-05-31 17:27:13           2     5555161
2020-05-31 17:27:49           3     5555161
2020-05-31 17:28:49           4     5555161
...                         ...         ...
2020-06-01 11:22:39        1029     5555161
2020-06-01 11:23:39        1030     5555161
2020-06-01 11:24:39        1031     5555161
2020-06-01 11:25:39        1032     5555161
2020-06-01 11:26:39        1033     5555161
```

I want to plot it by hour/date and show the counter of each hour.

So far, I've been able to plot this way :

```
df1 = df.groupby([df.index.hour, 'PanelistID'])['PanelistID'].count().unstack().plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

**My goal is to merge the records to create this form:**

```
Date                 Amount
2020-05-31 17        60
2020-05-31 18        58
2020-05-31 19        60
...            ... 
2020-06-01 11        42
```

**such that every hour I will sum all the records that I have for that specific hour (and date!) and plot it by the hour and date.**

currently, if I have the following records :

```
2020-05-31 17:27:49           3     5555161
2020-05-31 17:28:49           4     5555161
...                         ...         ...
2020-06-01 17:22:39        1000     5555161
2020-06-01 17:23:39        1001     5555161
```

The value of "17" on the x-axis will show the data from both 31/5 and 6/1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df.index.hour` drops the dates and gives you the hour only. I think you want `.floor`:

```
 df1 = df.groupby([df.index.floor('H'), 'PanelistID'])['PanelistID'].count().unstack().plot(kind='bar')
```

Also, if you only have one `PanelistID`, you don't need to group by `PanelistID`:

```
 df1 = df.groupby(df.index.floor('H'))['PanelistID'].count().plot(kind='bar')
```

If you have several `PanelistID`, you can use `value_counts`:

```
df1 = df.groupby(df.index.floor('H')['PanelistID'].value_counts().unstack().plot.bar()
```

Comment: .floor is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!